# Maintaining a points table to reduce rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to design an efficient automated task to clean up a reputation points table, similar to SO I suppose.

If a user reads an article, comments on an article and/or shares an article, I give my members some reputation points. If my member does all three of these for example, there would be three separate rows in that DB table. When showing the members points, I simply use a SUM query to count all points for that member.

Now, with a million active members, with high reputation, there are many, many rows in my table and would somehow like to clean them up. Using a Cron Job, I would like to merge all reputation rows for each member, older than 3-months, into one row. For example:

```
  user     |  repTask                      |  repPoints   |  repDate
-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
  10001    +  Commented on article         |  5           |  2012-11-12 08:40:32
  10001    +  Read an article              |  2           |  2012-06-12 12:32:01
  10001    +  Shared an article            |  10          |  2012-06-04 17:39:44
  10001    +  Read an article              |  2           |  2012-05-19 01:04:11
```

Would become:

```
  user     |  repTask                      |  repPoints   |  repDate
-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
  10001    +  Commented on article         |  5           |  2012-11-12 08:40:32
  10001    +  (merged points)              |  14          |  Now()
```

Or (merging months):

```
  user     |  repTask                      |  repPoints   |  repDate
-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
  10001    +  Commented on article         |  5           |  2012-11-12 08:40:32
  10001    +  (Merged for 06/2012)         |  12          |  Now()
  10001    +  (Merged for 05/2012)         |  2           |  Now()
```

Anything after 3-months is considered legitimate, anything before may need to be revoked in-case of cheating, hence why I state 3-months.

First of all, is this a good idea? I'm trying to avoid, say in 3 years time, having 100's of millions of rows. If it's not a good idea to merge points, is there a better way to store the data as it's inputted. I obviously cannot change what's already inputted but could make it better for the future.

If this is a good idea, I'm struggling to come up with an efficient query to modify the data. I'm not looking for exact code but if somebody could help describe a suitable query that could merge all points older than 3-months, for each user, or merge all points older than 3-months into separate months, for each user, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it that way, with cron jobs, but how about this:
Create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) or [procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) so that anytime a point is added, it updates a `total` column in the users table, and anytime a point is revoked the `total` column is subtracted from?

This way, no matter how many millions or billions of rows in the points table, you don't have to query those to get the total points results.  You could even have separate columns for months or years.  Also, since you're not deleting any rows you can go back and retroactively revoke a point from, say, a year ago if needed.

Comment: Great idea! I'm not fantastic with triggers or procedures but this is a good reason to learn a bit more about them.